# How to make an ArrayBuffer of ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala, collections

I want a two-dimensional array of ArrayBuffer

Something like this:

```
var myRowOfStrings = new ArrayBuffer[String]
val myArrayOfRows = new ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer] // To store many ArrayBuffer[String]
```

But the Scala compiler doesn't like the second declaration:

```
scala> val myArrayOfRows = new ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer]
<console>:8: error: class ArrayBuffer takes type parameters
       val myArrayOfRows = new ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer]
                                       ^
```

Have I got the syntax wrong?

Or is an ArrayBuffer of ArrayBuffer not possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ArrayBuffer` objects require a type. It says so in the error message.

You need to tell the compiler what type of `ArrayBuffer` you want.

```
scala> import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

scala> val myArrayOfRows = new ArrayBuffer[ArrayBuffer[String]]
myArrayOfRows: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String]] = ArrayBuffer()
```

Consider doing this if its easier.

```
type Row = ArrayBuffer[String]
var myRowOfStrings = new Row
val myArrayOfRows = new ArrayBuffer[Row]
```

Answer (score 0):

Import ArrayBuffer before applying it:

```scala
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
var e = ArrayBuffer("a", "b", "c")
```

```
scala> e: scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer[String] = ArrayBuffer(a, b, c)
```